# Property 'isFetching' does not exist on type 'never' but works when object is spread

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, redux

How come I get this Typescript error `Property 'isFetching' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)` for the snippet below

```
const mapStateToProps = (
  state: AppState,
  ownProps: AuthenticationPageProps
): IMapStateToProps => ({
  isFetching: state.authentication.isFetching,
  user: state.authentication.user
});
```

But if I spread the object, it works as expected?

```
const mapStateToProps = (
  state: AppState,
  ownProps: AuthenticationPageProps
): IMapStateToProps => {
  const { isFetching, user } = state.authentication;
  return { isFetching, user };
};
```

This snippet works as expected as well:

```
const mapStateToProps = (
  state: AppState,
  ownProps: AuthenticationPageProps
): IMapStateToProps => ({
  isFetching: state.authentication["isFetching"],
  user: state.authentication["user"],
});
```

Below is what I see in my developer tools when I print `props`

[image]

Here is the interface for `IMapStateToProps`

```
interface IMapStateToProps {
  isFetching: boolean;
  user: User;
}
```

More interfaces

```
export interface AuthenticationState {
  isFetching: boolean;
  user: User;
  errors: Error[];
}

export interface User {
  email?: string;
}

export interface Error {
  message: string;
  status: string;
}

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authentication: authenticationReducer, // authenticationReducer returns type: AuthenticationState
});

export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

Reducer:

```
import {
  LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
  LOGOUT_REQUEST,
  LOGOUT_FAILURE,
  LOGIN_FAILURE,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_REQUEST,
  REGISTER_FAILURE,
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_REQUEST,
  AuthenticationState,
  AuthenticationActionTypes,
  CHECK_LOGGED_IN_REQUEST,
  CHECK_LOGGED_IN_SUCCESS,
  CHECK_LOGGED_IN_FAILURE,
} from "../../types/Authentication";

export const AuthenticationReducerDefaultState = {
  errors: [],
  isFetching: false,
  user: {},
};

export const authenticationReducer = (
  state = AuthenticationReducerDefaultState,
  action: AuthenticationActionTypes
): AuthenticationState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_REQUEST:
    case LOGOUT_REQUEST:
    case REGISTER_REQUEST:
    case CHECK_LOGGED_IN_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
      };
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        user: action.user,
      };
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, isFetching: false };
    case CHECK_LOGGED_IN_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, isFetching: false };
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, isFetching: false };
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, isFetching: false };
    case LOGOUT_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, isFetching: false };
    case REGISTER_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, isFetching: false };
    case CHECK_LOGGED_IN_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, isFetching: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you post the AppState type.

Comment: @RaduDiță updated! please let me know if I am forgetting something

Comment: Could you post your authenticationReducer reducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial state is not the same type as the returned state.

```
export interface AuthenticationState {
  isFetching: boolean;
  user: User;
  errors: Error[];
}

export const AuthenticationReducerDefaultState = {
  errors: [], //Type never
  isFetching: false,
  user: {}, //Type {} not type User
};
```

You could fix that with:

```
export interface AuthenticationState {
  isFetching: boolean;
  user: User | {}; //Note the union type 
  errors: Error[];
}

export const AuthenticationReducerDefaultState = <AuthenticationState>{
  errors: [], 
  isFetching: false,
  user: {},
};


//Also should freeze the state as you would not want accidental mutations. 
export const AuthenticationReducerDefaultState = Object.freeze<AuthenticationState>({
  errors: [], 
  isFetching: false,
  user: {},
});
```